# Should I split this model and table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, sti

I would like to create simple ResumeBank app.

**Issue**:

As user I would like to add only two Resumes.
Forms for this both Resumes are different with only two fields. 
Resumes have 12 the same attributes but 2 are diferent.

**Question**:

Should I split that Resume model and tables to ex: PolishResume and EnglishResume, polish_remsumes and english_remsumes?

Or maybe should I use STI and create PolishResume < Resume and use one table.

What are disadvantages of splitting option?

Comment: The user needs to fill all the 12 attributes and pass the 2 resumes always?

Comment: User have to fill 10 attributes and be able to create english resume but this is obligatory. But in most cases he will create 2 resumes.

Comment: Those same attributes will always have the same value if the user has 2 resumes for example?

Comment: I would like to allow user choose which values can be the same and which could be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like classic inheritance should solve it

```
class ResumeBase{...}
class ResumeWith12Forms: public: ResumeBase{
     //use options to determine which unique 2 forms to show
     //options could be an enum or even boolean
     ResumeWith12Forms(options){ };
}

class User{ std::vector< std::shared_ptr<ResumeBase> userResume; }
```